# Change element by click like PHPAdmin

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, text, phpmyadmin

I am beginner of js. I want to make a editor like PHPAdmin. When click its table, the field will change to text-area. When click some where else outside of the text-area, it will change back to the filed and execute the sql.

Following is what I suppose to write with jQuery, I am totally not understand how should I code it further, please advice.

```
$('#editor #gird_edit').bind({
  click: function() { //When Click
      var content = $(this).text(); // read what is in the filed
      $("#gird_edit").text('<textarea>'+a+'</textarea>'); // This is not work, will only add html code,not change to text-area
  },
  /* ??? */: function() { //Outside click of the text-area 
      var content = $(this).text(); // read what is in the text-area
      $("#gird_edit").text(????);  // change back to the filed 
  }
})
```

Html

```
<div id='editor'>
   <div id='gird_edit'>hallo world</div>
   <div id='gird_edit'>hallo world 2</div>
   <div id='gird_edit'>hallo world 3</div>
</div>
```

I only have 3 reputations, just joined yesterday...I am sorry for that I cannot vote you since it requires 15 reputations. However, I will very appreciate you help!!

Comment: You can't have `id='gird_edit'` on multple DIVs, since IDs have to be unique; you probably should be using a class instead of ID. Regarding your overall goal, take a look at the [Jeditable plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to detect clicks outside of an element, just detect them on the whole page, and throw out any that come from inside the element.  In other words:

```
$('body').on('click', : function(e) { //Outside click of the text-area 
    if ($(this).parents().is('#gird_edit')) return false;
    var content = $('textarea').text(); // read what is in the text-area
    $("#gird_edit").text(????);  // change back to the filed 
});
```

However, it sounds like what you're really looking for is a "blur" handler, which will trigger whenever someone was inside a textarea and just left it; you can make one of those the same basic way you made your click handler:

```
$('#gird_edit textarea').bind({
    blur: function() {
        // do the reverse of the click handler
}
```

Comment: this works!, thank you very much!! One more question, when I try to change div to text-area, $("#gird_edit").text('<textarea>'+content+'</textarea>'); will only output the html, not changing the visual to text-area, what should I do with this?

Comment: Use `.html()` rather than `.text()`.

Comment: sorry, it doest work well....am I wrong with something? $('#editor #gird_edit').bind({
      click: function() {
         $(this).html('<textarea id="gird_edit">'+$(this).text()+'</textarea>');
      },
      blur: function() {
         $(this).html('<div id="gird_edit">'+$(this).text()+'</div>');
      }
    });

Comment: So, quick point of etiquette here on Stack Overflow: if you have a new question, it's almost always better to ask it as a new question, rather than asking it in the comments.  SO's creators deliberately designed the comments to be more awkward than the questions/answers to encourage this.  If you post a new Stack Overflow question with your question about .text/.html, I'm sure between myself, Barmar, and everyone else here on SO, you'll have an answer pretty quick :-)